# infinite scroll works only once

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I took the code from this tutorial:
https://www.senaidbacinovic.com/learn/jquery-infinite-scroll-tutorial
Just changed the query and driver,but 'infinite scrollbar' posts the offset and limit only once.What might be the problem?

data.php

```
 $conn = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;ServerNode=$host;Database=$db_name;CHAR_AS_UTF8=TRUE;", $username, $password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $limit =$_POST['limit'];
    
    $sql='SELECT "DocNum"
    ,T0."customer"
 FROM tt where "DocNum" LIKE \'214%\' ORDER BY "DocNum" DESC LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$start;
        $sql_exec=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
        echo $sql;
        if (odbc_num_fields($sql_exec) > 0)
            {
            $response = "";

            while($data = odbc_fetch_array($sql_exec)) {
                $response .= '
                    <div>
                        <h2>'.odbc_Result($sql_exec,1).'</h2>
                        <p>'.odbc_Result($sql_exec,2).'</p>
                    </div>
                ';
            }

            exit($response);
        } else
            exit('reachedMax');
    }
```

index.html javascript

```
var start = 0;
        var limit = 21;
        var reachedMax = false;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
                getData();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
           getData();
        });

        function getData() {
            if (reachedMax)
                return;

            $.ajax({
               url: 'data.php',
               method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
               data: {
                   getData: 1,
                   start: start,
                   limit: limit
               },
               success: function(response) {
                    if (response == "reachedMax")
                        reachedMax = true;
                    else {
                        start += limit;
                        $(".results").append(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**Edit: I changed nothing and now it works..I still wonder the reason though :)**

Comment: Maybe `console.log($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()))`

Comment: Thank you, it is working without doing anything, but I might try this next time.Having a lot of problems with infinite scrolbars. @mplungjan

Comment: I could not think of anything else. The code looked ok assuming the backend has more than 0+limit data

Comment: If it now works without you changing the code, it might be the browser cache. Some browsers do cache quite aggressively. Try refreshing your web page with Ctrl + R or Ctrl + F5 when loading edited frontend code.

Comment: It is doing the same thing again and I tried those but did't work @Apodemus

Comment: but yes it is about browsers, I used another browser and it worked again..... @Apodemus

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951187/javascript-file-not-updating-no-matter-what-i-do) might provide a useful solution. Caching can really be a pain sometimes.

Comment: thank you so much I'll check @Apodemus